# Convert text to comments

Tags: php, html, mysql, comments, smarty

**Background (very simplified):** I have an onlineshop and a selectbox. I got many articles and many selectboxes. Because of that I had to add comments to the selectboxes with php, so that they differ in the DB.

**Problem (also very simplified):** When Im loading a data set (I hope Im spelling it correctly) than Im obviously getting the selection + the comment.

**Problem (more simplified):**

I got this:

```
<td>VariantXYZ <!-- randomID --></td>
```

Is displayed like this (without the blue color):

```
VariantXYZ <!-- randomID -->
```

**Question:** How do I convert the comment to a comment?^^

**EDIT:** I have tried the preg_replace method before too but it didn't work for me because I forgot that I use smarty ;-)

My code is the following:

```
[{foreach from=$orderArticles item=listitem}]
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" class="edittext" style="background-color:#e2d9d9; border: 1px solid #fff">[{ $listitem->oxorderarticles__oxamount->value }] * </td>
                <td valign="top" class="edittext" style="background-color:#e2d9d9; border: 1px solid #fff">&nbsp;[{ $listitem->oxorderarticles__oxartnum->value }]</td>
                <td valign="top" class="edittext" style="background-color:#e2d9d9; border: 1px solid #fff">&nbsp;[{ $listitem->oxorderarticles__oxtitle->getRawValue()|oxtruncate:20:""|strip_tags }][{if $listitem->oxwrapping__oxname->value}]&nbsp;([{$listitem->oxwrapping__oxname->value}])&nbsp;[{/if}]</td>
                <td valign="top" class="edittext" style="background-color:#e2d9d9; border: 1px solid #fff">&nbsp;[{ $listitem->oxorderarticles__oxselvariant->value }]</td>

                [{if $edit->isNettoMode() }]
                    <td valign="top" class="edittext">&nbsp;&nbsp;[{ $listitem->getNetPriceFormated() }] [{ $edit->oxorder__oxcurrency->value }]</td>
                [{else}]
                    <td valign="top" class="edittext" style="background-color:#e2d9d9; border: 1px solid #fff">&nbsp;&nbsp;[{ $listitem->getTotalBrutPriceFormated() }] [{ $edit->oxorder__oxcurrency->value }]</td>
                [{/if}]
                [{ if $listitem->getPersParams() }]
                <td valign="top" class="edittext">
                    [{foreach key=sVar from=$listitem->getPersParams() item=aParam name=persparams}]
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;,&nbsp;<em>
                            [{if $smarty.foreach.persparams.first && $smarty.foreach.persparams.last}]
                                [{ oxmultilang ident="GENERAL_LABEL" }]
                            [{else}]
                                [{$sVar}] :
                            [{/if}]
                            [{$aParam}]
                        </em>
                    [{/foreach}]
                </td>
                [{/if}]
            </tr>
            [{/foreach}]
```

I want to use preg_replace on $listitem->oxorderarticles__oxselvariant->value, which I have done like this:

```
[{$listitem = preg_replace( "/&lt;!--(.|\s)*?--&gt;/" , "###" , $listitem )}]
```

But it deletes all fields with $listitem.

I should have mentioned that I use smarty in the first place. Sorry for that.

Comment: Could you not use aregular expression and find the <!-- and --> and change them ? something like `$content = preg_replace( '/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/' , '###' , $content );`

Comment: what do you mean by "When Im loading a data set"? To a database? Show us your code.

Comment: I have edited my first post. Would be glad if you can help me.

Comment: See smarty's regex_replace,  http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.regex.replace.tpl

Answer (score 0):

I think this might have to do with the encoding of your string. Could you try this before outputting it to the page:

```
$text = html_entity_decode($text);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

It might help. But what you really need to do is to look at the source code to see what's really there. Another option could be:

```
$text = stripslashes($text);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

I really cannot tell what your exact problem is. I also found this in the Smarty documentation:

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.escape.html.tpl

Yet another way to change the way characters are encoded. You could try:

```
{$variable nofilter}
```

and see if that helps. But this is a problem with many possible causes so there's no garantee. You need to follow the data step by step to debug this.

Comment: I have edited my first post. Would be glad if you can help me.

Comment: Sorry, I have no knowledge of 'Smarty'.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of your question? Clearly the software you're using has an effect on the encoding. You need to find out how you can disable or reverse this effect. The obvious thing to use is PHP. Using Javascript for it is really not practical, if it is even possible.

Comment: I looked in the smartly documentation for a few minutes and found this: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.escape.html.tpl Perhaps this is your problem?